# .net collection for fast insert/delete

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I need to maintain a roster of connected clients that are very shortlived and frequently go up and down. Due to the potential number of clients I need a collection that supports fast insert/delete. Suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### C5 Generic Collection Library

The best implementations I have found in C# and C++ are these -- for C#/CLI:

- http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/ITU-TR-2006-76.pdf
- http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

It's well researched, has extensible unit tests, and since February they also have implemented the common interfaces in .Net which makes it a lot easier to work with the collections. They were featured on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Peter-Sestoft-C5-Generic-Collection-Library-for-C-and-CLI/) and they've done extensive performance testing on the collections.

If you are using data-structures anyway these researchers have a [red-black-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) implementation in their library, similar to what you find if you fire up Lütz reflector and have a look in System.Data's internal structures :p. Insert-complexity: O(log(n)).

### Lock-free C++ collections

Then, if you can [allow for some C++ interop](http://blog.rednael.com/2008/08/29/MarshallingUsingNativeDLLsInNET.aspx) and you absolutely need the speed and want as little overhead as possible, then these lock-free ADTs from Dmitriy V'jukov are probably the best you can get in this world, outperforming Intel's concurrent library of ADTs.

- http://groups.google.com/group/lock-free

I've read some of the code and it's really the makings of someone well versed in how these things are put together. VC++ can do native C++ interop without annoying boundaries. [http://www.swig.org/](http://groups.google.com/group/lock-free) can otherwise help you wrap C++ interfaces for consumption in .Net, or you can do it yourself through P/Invoke.

### Microsoft's Take

They have written tutorials, [this one implementing a rather unpolished skip-list in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573.aspx), and discussing other types of data-structures. (There's a better [SkipList at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/skiplist1.aspx), which is very polished and implement the interfaces in a well-behaved manner.) They also have a few data-structures bundled with .Net, namely the [HashTable/Dictionary<,>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz.aspx) and [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727.aspx). Of course there's the "ResizeArray"/List type as well together with a stack and queue, but they are all "linear" on search.

### Google's perf-tools

If you wish to speed up the time it takes for memory-allocation you can use google's perf-tools. They are available at google code and they contain a [very interesting multi-threaded malloc-implementation (TCMalloc)](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) which shows much more consistent timing than the normal malloc does. You could use this together with the lock-free structures above to really go crazy with performance.

### Improving response times with memoization

You can also use memoization on functions to improve performance through caching, something interesting if you're using e.g. [F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598504). F# also allows C++ interop, so you're OK there.

### O(k)

There's also the possibility of doing something on your own using the research which has been done on [bloom-filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which allow O(k) lookup complexity where k is a constant that depends on the number of hash-functions you have implemented. This is how google's BigTable has been implemented. These filter will get you the element if it's in the set or possibly with a very low likeliness an element which is not the one you're looking for (see the graph at wikipedia -- it's approaching P(wrong_key) -> 0.01 as size is around 10000 elements, but you can go around this by implementing further hash-functions/reducing the set.

I haven't searched for .Net implementations of this, but since the hashing calculations are independent you can use [MS's performance team's implementation of Tasks to speed that up.](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/02/8567093.aspx)

### "My" take -- randomize to reach average O(log n)

As it happens I just did a coursework involving data-structures. In this case we used C++, but it's very easy to translate to C#. We built three different data-structures; a bloom-filter, a skip-list and [random binary search tree](http://gcu.googlecode.com/files/09BinarySearchTrees.pdf).

See the code and analysis after the last paragraph.

### Hardware-based "collections"

Finally, to make my answer "complete", if you truly need speed you can use something like [Routing-tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_information_base) or [Content-addressable memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_addressable_memory) . This allows you to very quickly O(1) in principle get a "hash"-to-value lookup of your data.

### Random Binary Search Tree/Bloom Filter C++ code

I would really appreciate feedback if you find mistakes in the code, or just pointers on how I can do it better (or with better usage of templates). Note that the bloom filter isn't like it would be in real life; normally you don't have to be able to delete from it and then it much much more space efficient than the hack I did to allow the *delete* to be tested.

**DataStructure.h**

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_H_
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H_

class DataStructure
{
public:
    DataStructure() {countAdd=0; countDelete=0;countFind=0;}
    virtual ~DataStructure() {}

    void resetCountAdd() {countAdd=0;}
    void resetCountFind() {countFind=0;}
    void resetCountDelete() {countDelete=0;}

    unsigned int getCountAdd(){return countAdd;}
    unsigned int getCountDelete(){return countDelete;}
    unsigned int getCountFind(){return countFind;}

protected:
    unsigned int countAdd;
    unsigned int countDelete;
    unsigned int countFind;
};

#endif /*DATASTRUCTURE_H_*/
```

**Key.h**

```
#ifndef KEY_H_
#define KEY_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int keyLength = 128;

class Key : public string
{
public:
    Key():string(keyLength, ' ') {}
    Key(const char in[]): string(in){}
    Key(const string& in): string(in){}

    bool operator<(const string& other);
    bool operator>(const string& other);
    bool operator==(const string& other);

    virtual ~Key() {}
};

#endif /*KEY_H_*/
```

**Key.cpp**

```
#include "Key.h"

bool Key::operator<(const string& other)
{
    return compare(other) < 0;
};

bool Key::operator>(const string& other)
{
    return compare(other) > 0;
};

bool Key::operator==(const string& other)
{
    return compare(other) == 0;
}
```

**BloomFilter.h**

```
#ifndef BLOOMFILTER_H_
#define BLOOMFILTER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "Key.h"
#include "DataStructure.h"

#define LONG_BIT 32
#define bitmask(val) (unsigned long)(1 << (LONG_BIT - (val % LONG_BIT) - 1))

// TODO: Implement RW-locking on the reads/writes to the bitmap.

class BloomFilter : public DataStructure
{
public:
    BloomFilter(){}
    BloomFilter(unsigned long length){init(length);}
    virtual ~BloomFilter(){}

    void init(unsigned long length);
    void dump();

    void add(const Key& key);
    void del(const Key& key);

    /**
     * Returns true if the key IS BELIEVED to exist, false if it absolutely doesn't.
     */
    bool testExist(const Key& key, bool v = false);

private:
    unsigned long hash1(const Key& key);
    unsigned long hash2(const Key& key);
    bool exist(const Key& key);
    void getHashAndIndicies(unsigned long& h1, unsigned long& h2, int& i1, int& i2, const Key& key);
    void getCountIndicies(const int i1, const unsigned long h1,
        const int i2, const unsigned long h2, int& i1_c, int& i2_c);

    vector<unsigned long> m_tickBook;
    vector<unsigned int> m_useCounts;
    unsigned long m_length; // number of bits in the bloom filter
    unsigned long m_pockets; //the number of pockets

    static const unsigned long m_pocketSize; //bits in each pocket
};

#endif /*BLOOMFILTER_H_*/
```

**BloomFilter.cpp**

```
#include "BloomFilter.h"

const unsigned long BloomFilter::m_pocketSize = LONG_BIT;

void BloomFilter::init(unsigned long length)
{
    //m_length = length;
    m_length = (unsigned long)((2.0*length)/log(2))+1;
    m_pockets = (unsigned long)(ceil(double(m_length)/m_pocketSize));
    m_tickBook.resize(m_pockets);

    // my own (allocate nr bits possible to store in the other vector)
    m_useCounts.resize(m_pockets * m_pocketSize);

    unsigned long i; for(i=0; i< m_pockets; i++) m_tickBook[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m_useCounts.size(); i++) m_useCounts[i] = 0; // my own
}

unsigned long BloomFilter::hash1(const Key& key)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    unsigned int i=0; for (i=0; i< key.length(); i++){
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + key.c_str()[i]; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }

    double d_hash = (double) hash;

    d_hash *= (0.5*(sqrt(5)-1));
    d_hash -= floor(d_hash);
    d_hash *= (double)m_length;

    return (unsigned long)floor(d_hash);
}

unsigned long BloomFilter::hash2(const Key& key)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    unsigned int i=0; for (i=0; i< key.length(); i++){
        hash = key.c_str()[i] + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
    }
    double d_hash = (double) hash;

    d_hash *= (0.5*(sqrt(5)-1));
    d_hash -= floor(d_hash);
    d_hash *= (double)m_length;

    return (unsigned long)floor(d_hash);
}

bool BloomFilter::testExist(const Key& key, bool v){
    if(exist(key)) {
        if(v) cout<<"Key "<< key<<" is in the set"<<endl;
        return true;
    }else {
        if(v) cout<<"Key "<< key<<" is not in the set"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
}

void BloomFilter::dump()
{
    cout<<m_pockets<<" Pockets: ";

    // I changed u to %p because I wanted it printed in hex.
    unsigned long i; for(i=0; i< m_pockets; i++) printf("%p ", (void*)m_tickBook[i]);
    cout<<endl;
}

void BloomFilter::add(const Key& key)
{
    unsigned long h1, h2;
    int i1, i2;
    int i1_c, i2_c;

    // tested!

    getHashAndIndicies(h1, h2, i1, i2, key);
    getCountIndicies(i1, h1, i2, h2, i1_c, i2_c);

    m_tickBook[i1] = m_tickBook[i1] | bitmask(h1);
    m_tickBook[i2] = m_tickBook[i2] | bitmask(h2);

    m_useCounts[i1_c] = m_useCounts[i1_c] + 1;
    m_useCounts[i2_c] = m_useCounts[i2_c] + 1;

    countAdd++;
}

void BloomFilter::del(const Key& key)
{
    unsigned long h1, h2;
    int i1, i2;
    int i1_c, i2_c;

    if (!exist(key)) throw "You can't delete keys which are not in the bloom filter!";

    // First we need the indicies into m_tickBook and the
    // hashes.
    getHashAndIndicies(h1, h2, i1, i2, key);

    // The index of the counter is the index into the bitvector
    // times the number of bits per vector item plus the offset into
    // that same vector item.
    getCountIndicies(i1, h1, i2, h2, i1_c, i2_c);

    // We need to update the value in the bitvector in order to
    // delete the key.
    m_useCounts[i1_c] = (m_useCounts[i1_c] == 1 ? 0 : m_useCounts[i1_c] - 1);
    m_useCounts[i2_c] = (m_useCounts[i2_c] == 1 ? 0 : m_useCounts[i2_c] - 1);

    // Now, if we depleted the count for a specific bit, then set it to
    // zero, by anding the complete unsigned long with the notted bitmask
    // of the hash value
    if (m_useCounts[i1_c] == 0)
        m_tickBook[i1] = m_tickBook[i1] & ~(bitmask(h1));
    if (m_useCounts[i2_c] == 0)
        m_tickBook[i2] = m_tickBook[i2] & ~(bitmask(h2));

    countDelete++;
}

bool BloomFilter::exist(const Key& key)
{
    unsigned long h1, h2;
    int i1, i2;

    countFind++;

    getHashAndIndicies(h1, h2, i1, i2, key);

    return  ((m_tickBook[i1] & bitmask(h1)) > 0) &&
            ((m_tickBook[i2] & bitmask(h2)) > 0);
}

/*
 * Gets the values of the indicies for two hashes and places them in
 * the passed parameters. The index is into m_tickBook.
 */
void BloomFilter::getHashAndIndicies(unsigned long& h1, unsigned long& h2, int& i1,
    int& i2, const Key& key)
{
    h1 = hash1(key);
    h2 = hash2(key);
    i1 = (int) h1/m_pocketSize;
    i2 = (int) h2/m_pocketSize;
}

/*
 * Gets the values of the indicies into the count vector, which keeps
 * track of how many times a specific bit-position has been used.
 */
void BloomFilter::getCountIndicies(const int i1, const unsigned long h1,
    const int i2, const unsigned long h2, int& i1_c, int& i2_c)
{
    i1_c = i1*m_pocketSize + h1%m_pocketSize;
    i2_c = i2*m_pocketSize + h2%m_pocketSize;
}
```

** RBST.h **

```
#ifndef RBST_H_
#define RBST_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "Key.h"
#include "DataStructure.h"

#define BUG(str) printf("%s:%d FAILED SIZE INVARIANT: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, str);

using namespace std;

class RBSTNode;
class RBSTNode: public Key
{
public:
    RBSTNode(const Key& key):Key(key)
    {
        m_left =NULL;
        m_right = NULL;
        m_size = 1U; // the size of one node is 1.
    }
    virtual ~RBSTNode(){}

    string setKey(const Key& key){return Key(key);}

    RBSTNode* left(){return m_left; }
    RBSTNode* right(){return m_right;}

    RBSTNode* setLeft(RBSTNode* left) { m_left = left; return this; }
    RBSTNode* setRight(RBSTNode* right) { m_right =right; return this; }

#ifdef DEBUG
    ostream& print(ostream& out)
    {
        out << "Key(" << *this << ", m_size: " << m_size << ")";
        return out;
    }
#endif

    unsigned int size() { return m_size; }

    void setSize(unsigned int val)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        this->print(cout);
        cout << "::setSize(" << val << ") called." << endl;
#endif

        if (val == 0) throw "Cannot set the size below 1, then just delete this node.";
        m_size = val;
    }

    void incSize() {
#ifdef DEBUG
        this->print(cout);
        cout << "::incSize() called" << endl;
#endif

        m_size++;
    }

    void decrSize()
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        this->print(cout);
        cout << "::decrSize() called" << endl;
#endif

        if (m_size == 1) throw "Cannot decrement size below 1, then just delete this node.";
        m_size--;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    unsigned int size(RBSTNode* x);
#endif

private:
    RBSTNode(){}
    RBSTNode* m_left;
    RBSTNode* m_right;
    unsigned int m_size;
};

class RBST : public DataStructure
{
public:
    RBST() {
        m_size = 0;
        m_head = NULL;
        srand(time(0));
    };

    virtual ~RBST() {};

    /**
     * Tries to add key into the tree and will return
     *      true  for a new item added
     *      false if the key already is in the tree.
     *
     * Will also have the side-effect of printing to the console if v=true.
     */
    bool add(const Key& key, bool v=false);

    /**
     * Same semantics as other add function, but takes a string,
     * but diff name, because that'll cause an ambiguity because of inheritance.
     */
    bool addString(const string& key);

    /**
     * Deletes a key from the tree if that key is in the tree.
     * Will return
     *      true  for success and
     *      false for failure.
     *
     * Will also have the side-effect of printing to the console if v=true.
     */
    bool del(const Key& key, bool v=false);

    /**
     * Tries to find the key in the tree and will return
     *      true if the key is in the tree and
     *      false if the key is not.
     *
     * Will also have the side-effect of printing to the console if v=true.
     */
    bool find(const Key& key, bool v = false);

    unsigned int count() { return m_size; }

#ifdef DEBUG
    int dump(char sep = ' ');
    int dump(RBSTNode* target, char sep);
    unsigned int size(RBSTNode* x);
#endif

private:
    RBSTNode* randomAdd(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key);
    RBSTNode* addRoot(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key);
    RBSTNode* rightRotate(RBSTNode* target);
    RBSTNode* leftRotate(RBSTNode* target);

    RBSTNode* del(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key);
    RBSTNode* join(RBSTNode* left, RBSTNode* right);

    RBSTNode* find(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key);

    RBSTNode* m_head;
    unsigned int m_size;
};

#endif /*RBST_H_*/
```

** RBST.cpp **

```
#include "RBST.h"

bool RBST::add(const Key& key, bool v){
    unsigned int oldSize = m_size;
    m_head = randomAdd(m_head, key);
    if (m_size > oldSize){
        if(v) cout<<"Node "<<key<< " is added into the tree."<<endl;
        return true;
    }else {
        if(v) cout<<"Node "<<key<< " is already in the tree."<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(v) cout<<endl;
};

bool RBST::addString(const string& key) {
    return add(Key(key), false);
}

bool RBST::del(const Key& key, bool v){
    unsigned oldSize= m_size;
    m_head = del(m_head, key);
    if (m_size < oldSize) {
        if(v) cout<<"Node "<<key<< " is deleted from the tree."<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if(v) cout<< "Node "<<key<< " is not in the tree."<<endl;
        return false;
    }
};

bool RBST::find(const Key& key, bool v){
    RBSTNode* ret = find(m_head, key);
    if (ret == NULL){
        if(v) cout<< "Node "<<key<< " is not in the tree."<<endl;
        return false;
    }else {
        if(v) cout<<"Node "<<key<< " is in the tree."<<endl;
        return true;
    }
};

#ifdef DEBUG
int RBST::dump(char sep){
    int ret = dump(m_head, sep);
    cout<<"SIZE: " <<ret<<endl;
    return ret;
};

int RBST::dump(RBSTNode* target, char sep){
    if (target == NULL) return 0;
    int ret = dump(target->left(), sep);
    cout<< *target<<sep;
    ret ++;
    ret += dump(target->right(), sep);
    return ret;
};
#endif

/**
 * Rotates the tree around target, so that target's left
 * is the new root of the tree/subtree and updates the subtree sizes.
 *
 *(target)  b               (l) a
 *         / \      right      / \
 *        a   ?     ---->     ?   b
 *       / \                     / \
 *      ?   x                   x   ?
 *
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::rightRotate(RBSTNode* target) // private
{
    if (target == NULL) throw "Invariant failure, target is null"; // Note: may be removed once tested.
    if (target->left() == NULL) throw "You cannot rotate right around a target whose left node is NULL!";

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout    <<"Right-rotating b-node ";
    target->print(cout);
    cout    << " for a-node ";
    target->left()->print(cout);
    cout    << "." << endl;
#endif

    RBSTNode* l = target->left();
    int as0 = l->size();

    // re-order the sizes
    l->setSize( l->size() + (target->right() == NULL ? 0 : target->right()->size()) + 1); // a.size += b.right.size + 1; where b.right may be null.
    target->setSize( target->size() -as0 + (l->right() == NULL ? 0 : l->right()->size()) ); // b.size += -a_0_size + x.size where x may be null.

    // swap b's left (for a)
    target->setLeft(l->right());

    // and a's right (for b's left)
    l->setRight(target);

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout    << "A-node size: " << l->size() << ", b-node size: " << target->size() << "." << endl;
#endif

    // return the new root, a.
    return l;
};

/**
 * Like rightRotate, but the other way. See docs for rightRotate(RBSTNode*)
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::leftRotate(RBSTNode* target)
{
    if (target == NULL) throw "Invariant failure, target is null";
    if (target->right() == NULL) throw "You cannot rotate left around a target whose right node is NULL!";

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout    <<"Left-rotating a-node ";
    target->print(cout);
    cout    << " for b-node ";
    target->right()->print(cout);
    cout    << "." << endl;
#endif

    RBSTNode* r = target->right();
    int bs0 = r->size();

    // re-roder the sizes
    r->setSize(r->size() + (target->left() == NULL ? 0 : target->left()->size()) + 1);
    target->setSize(target->size() -bs0 + (r->left() == NULL ? 0 : r->left()->size()));

    // swap a's right (for b's left)
    target->setRight(r->left());

    // swap b's left (for a)
    r->setLeft(target);

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout    << "Left-rotation done: a-node size: " << target->size() << ", b-node size: " << r->size() << "." << endl;
#endif

    return r;
};

//
/**
 * Adds a key to the tree and returns the new root of the tree.
 * If the key already exists doesn't add anything.
 * Increments m_size if the key didn't already exist and hence was added.
 *
 * This function is not called from public methods, it's a helper function.
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::addRoot(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key)
{
    countAdd++;

    if (target == NULL) return new RBSTNode(key);

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "addRoot(";
    cout.flush();
    target->print(cout) << "," << key << ") called." << endl;
#endif

    if (*target < key)
    {
        target->setRight( addRoot(target->right(), key) );
        target->incSize(); // Should I?
        RBSTNode* res = leftRotate(target);
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (target->size() != size(target))
            BUG("in addRoot 1");
#endif
        return res;
    }

    target->setLeft( addRoot(target->left(), key) );
    target->incSize(); // Should I?
    RBSTNode* res = rightRotate(target);
#ifdef DEBUG
    if (target->size() != size(target))
        BUG("in addRoot 2");
#endif
    return res;
};

/**
 * This function is called from the public add(key) function,
 * and returns the new root node.
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::randomAdd(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key)
{
    countAdd++;

    if (target == NULL)
    {
        m_size++;
        return new RBSTNode(key);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "randomAdd(";
    target->print(cout) << ", \"" << key << "\") called." << endl;
#endif

    int r = (rand() % target->size()) + 1;

    // here is where we add the target as root!
    if (r == 1)
    {
        m_size++;   // TODO: Need to lock.
        return addRoot(target, key);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("randomAdd recursion part, ");
#endif

    // otherwise, continue recursing!
    if (*target <= key)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("target <= key\n");
#endif
        target->setRight( randomAdd(target->right(), key) );
        target->incSize(); // TODO: Need to lock.
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (target->right()->size() != size(target->right()))
            BUG("in randomAdd 1");
#endif
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("target > key\n");
#endif
        target->setLeft( randomAdd(target->left(), key) );
        target->incSize(); // TODO: Need to lock.
#ifdef DEBUG
        if (target->left()->size() != size(target->left()))
            BUG("in randomAdd 2");
#endif
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("randomAdd return part\n");
#endif

    m_size++;       // TODO: Need to lock.
    return target;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////  DEL FUNCTIONS ////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Deletes a node with the passed key.
 * Returns the root node.
 * Decrements m_size if something was deleted.
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::del(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key)
{
    countDelete++;

    if (target == NULL) return NULL;

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "del(";
    target->print(cout) << ", \"" << key << "\") called." << endl;
#endif

    RBSTNode* ret = NULL;

    // found the node to delete
    if (*target == key)
    {
        ret = join(target->left(), target->right());

        m_size--;
        delete target;

        return ret; // return the newly built joined subtree!
    }

    // store a temporary size before recursive deletion.
    unsigned int size = m_size;

    if (*target < key)  target->setRight( del(target->right(), key) );
    else                target->setLeft( del(target->left(), key) );

    // if the previous recursion changed the size, we need to decrement the size of this target too.
    if (m_size < size) target->decrSize();

#ifdef DEBUG
    if (RBST::size(target) != target->size())
        BUG("in del");
#endif

    return target;
};

/**
 * Joins the two subtrees represented by left and right
 * by randomly choosing which to make the root, weighted on the
 * size of the sub-tree.
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::join(RBSTNode* left, RBSTNode* right)
{
    if (left == NULL) return right;
    if (right == NULL) return left;

#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "join(";
    left->print(cout);
    cout << ",";
    right->print(cout) << ") called." << endl;
#endif

    // Find the chance that we use the left tree, based on its size over the total tree size.
    // 3 s.d. randomness :-p e.g. 60.3% chance.
    bool useLeft = ((rand()%1000) < (signed)((float)left->size()/(float)(left->size() + right->size()) * 1000.0));

    RBSTNode* subtree = NULL;

    if (useLeft)
    {
        subtree = join(left->right(), right);

        left->setRight(subtree)
            ->setSize((left->left() == NULL ? 0 : left->left()->size())
                        + subtree->size() + 1 );

#ifdef DEBUG
        if (size(left) != left->size())
            BUG("in join 1");
#endif

        return left;
    }

    subtree = join(right->left(), left);

    right->setLeft(subtree)
         ->setSize((right->right() == NULL ? 0 : right->right()->size())
                    + subtree->size() + 1);

#ifdef DEBUG
    if (size(right) != right->size())
        BUG("in join 2");
#endif

    return right;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////  FIND FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Tries to find the key in the tree starting
 * search from target.
 *
 * Returns NULL if it was not found.
 */
RBSTNode* RBST::find(RBSTNode* target, const Key& key)
{
    countFind++; // Could use private method only counting the first call.
    if (target == NULL) return NULL; // not found.
    if (*target == key) return target; // found (does string override ==?)
    if (*target < key) return find(target->right(), key); // search for gt to the right.
    return find(target->left(), key); // search for lt to the left.
};

#ifdef DEBUG

unsigned int RBST::size(RBSTNode* x)
{
    if (x == NULL) return 0;
    return 1 + size(x->left()) + size(x->right());
}

#endif
```

I'll save the SkipList for another time since it's already possible to find good implementations of a SkipList from the links and my version wasn't much different.

The graphs generated from the test-file are as follows:

**Graph showing time taken to add new items for BloomFilter, RBST and SkipList.**
[graph http://haf.se/content/dl/addtimer.png](http://haf.se/content/dl/addtimer.png)

**Graph showing time taken to find items for BloomFilter, RBST and SkipList**
[graph http://haf.se/content/dl/findtimer.png](http://haf.se/content/dl/findtimer.png)

**Graph showing time taken to delete items for BloomFilter, RBST and SkipList**
[graph http://haf.se/content/dl/deltimer.png](http://haf.se/content/dl/deltimer.png)

So as you can see, the random binary search tree was rather a lot better than the SkipList. The bloom filter lives up to its O(k).

Comment: Do you have any idea why C5 is not a part of .NET standard collection?

Comment: It was created after .Net was created. It is from a third party and the .Net collections are OK for most usages.

Comment: Henrik, could you tell me if you access/retrieve the item from a bloom filter? Or the second graph is about merely detecting the existence?

Comment: it's just about detecting non-existence. If you get a true back then it might (likely) exist. If you get a false then it definately doesn't exist. The time is pretty short as you can see, around 1½ ms.

Comment: Henrik, what about retrieving from a RBST?

Comment: I mean is it possible to access an item in BST? If I know the index, is it possible to get the item from the list back?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20073/discussion-between-nawfal-and-henrik)

Comment: Wow, what an answer! Usually the best answer to the question "fast insert/delete?" is simply "use the standard `Dictionary<Key,Value>`" or "use the standard `HashSet<T>`. But since we're talking about 3rd-party libraries anyway, if the built-in collections are missing something you need, consider whether the alternative collection types in [LoycCore](http://core.loyc.net) might meet your needs, such as [`BDictionary<Key,Value>` or `BMultiMap<Key,Value>`](http://core.loyc.net/collections/alists-part2.html)

Answer (score 11):

Consider the hash-based collections for this, e.g. [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727.aspx), [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx), which provide constant time performance for adding and removing elements.

More information from the .NET Framework Developer's Guide:

- [Hashtable and Dictionary Collection Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz.aspx)
- [HashSet Collection Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure? I believe adding to a regular list<T> is much faster than to a dictionary or hashset. Removing should be a [different story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544089/why-is-removing-by-index-from-an-ilist-performing-so-much-worse-than-removing-by?lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Well, how much do you need to query it? A linked-list has fast insert/delete (at any position), but isn't as quick to search as (for example) a dictionary / sorted-list. Alternatively, a straight list with a bit/value pair in each - i.e. "still has value". Just re-use *logically* empty cells before appending. Delete just clears the cell.

For reference types, "null" would do here. For value-types, `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Hashtable or strongly typed Dictionary<Client>. The client class might override GetHashCode to provide a faster hash code generation, or if using Hashtable you can optionally use an IHashCodeProvider.

Answer (score 1):

How do you need to find the clients? Is a Tuple/Dictionary necessary? You're more than likely to find something that solves your problem in the Jeffrey Richter's [Power Collections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) library which has lists, trees, most data structures you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I was very impressed by the Channel9 interview with Peter Sestoft:

[channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Peter-Sestoft-C5-Generic-Collection-Library-for-C-and-CLI/](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Peter-Sestoft-C5-Generic-Collection-Library-for-C-and-CLI/)

He is a professor at the Copenhagen IT University who helped to create the The C5 Generic Collection Library:

[www.itu.dk/research/c5/](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)

It might be overkill or it might be just the speedy collection you were looking for ...

hth,

-Mike

Comment: Yes! Beat you by 30 seconds! :D